# Rendering 'as JSON' in Grails with conditional operator doesn't render correctly

Tags: json, grails, groovy, rendering

Came across this strange result today trying to render a list of objects as JSON in Grails 2.0.4...(i know i'm gonna regret asking this on account of something right under my nose...**updated** 5/26, my prediction was correct, see below :-))

This works fine; the JSON renders correctly in the browser...

```
def products = [] //ArrayList of Product objects from service       
def model = (products) ? [products:products] : [products:"No products found"] 
render model as JSON
```

..so why doesn't this shortened version without `model` work?

```
def products = []       
render ((products) ? [products:products] : [products:"No products found"]) as JSON
```

The resulting JSON from the above code is output as a single line of text, so I suspect it's not picking up `as JSON`, but it's parenthesized correctly, so what's the deal?

> ['products':[com.test.domain.Product : null,
>   com.test.domain.Product...]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of `render`. When you provide arguments to `render` without braces like

`render model as JSON`

It makes an implicit adjustment setting up the `content-type` to `text/json`. But in the later case, you have unknowingly made the `render` to use the braces like [mark on the first brace after `render` makes render use the normal `render()`]

`render ((products) ? [products:products] : [products:"No products found"]) as JSON`.

In the above case, you have to pass in the named parameters to `render` mentioning the `contentType`, `text` or `model`, `status` etc. So in order to render the inline control logic as JSON in browser/view you have to do like below:

```
render(contentType: "application/json", text: [products: (products ?: "No products found")] as JSON)
```

You can also use `content-type` as `text/json`. I prefer `application/json`.

UPDATE
**Alternative Simplest Way:**
`render([products: (products ?: "No products found")] as JSON)`

Comment: Damnit, i'm invoking `render()` without even realizing it, thx, I ended up going with this using elements of your solution, it's a little shorter and avoids specifying the content type twice: `render(contentType: "text/json") { [products: (products ?: "No products found")]}`

Comment: This would work as well: `render ((products ? [products:products] : [products:"No products found"]) as JSON )`

Comment: @JamesKleeh Ace in the hole, nice!..and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @JamesKleeh Hats off. There is always a cleaner, better ans simpler way to do things. Thanks for showing that. :)

Comment: @JamesKleeh Here again: `render([products: (products ?: "No products found")] as JSON)`

Answer (score 3):

The essence of your problem here is that the groovy compiler interprets

```
render x as JSON
```

to mean

```
render (x as JSON)
```

but it interprets

```
render (x) as JSON
```

to mean

```
(render x) as JSON
```

If a method name (in this case `render`) is followed immediately by an opening parenthesis, then only code up to the matching closing parenthesis is considered to be the argument list. This is why you need an extra set of parentheses to say

```
render ((x) as JSON)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the reason. Try to use like this:

```
render(contentType: 'text/json') {[
    'products': products ? : "No products found"
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you do is calling render with the parameters in ( ), and then applying "as JSON" to the result!

Don't forget that leaving the parentheses out is just a shortcut for a method call, but the same rules still apply.