# Render Object and Value as JSON as ajax response

Tags: json, grails

I am trying to do the following:

```
render [assignedSchol:assignedSchol,scholType:scholType] as JSON
```

assignedSchol is an object, and scholType is just a value. I get a "No map entry allowed at this place error". any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754281/rendering-as-json-in-grails-with-conditional-operator-doesnt-render-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
render(contentType: "application/json") {[assignedSchol:assignedSchol,scholType:scholType]}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ia actually just realized i needed to just wrap it all in parentheses.. haha

Answer (score 3):

When you use one liner like you did **you must put the conversion in braces** like this:

```
render ( [assignedSchol:assignedSchol,scholType:scholType] as JSON )
```

---

But I think the above code returns json data as plain text format so I usually prefer doing it this way:

```
render(contentType: "text/json") {

            [assignedSchol:assignedSchol,scholType:scholType]

            }
```

Which gives me json data with response type json.