# Grails render named arguments are not allowed inside index operations

Tags: grails, groovy, render

In grails(currently using 2.2.1), with render, if I write something like this:

```
render [msg: msg] as JSON
```

Then it gives compile time error of "named arguments are not allowed inside index operations"

However if I write something like this:

```
def result=[msg: msg]
render result as JSON
```

Above works.

Wondering why its like that as I see no difference in assigning a map to another variable and using in render.Why unnecessary overhead of creating a separate variable?

Comment: I hope you got the importance of the usage of braces from the duplicate question's answer. So, in this particular case `render( [msg:msg] as JSON )` is needed.

Comment: Does groovy treat [ equal to ( in this case? @dmahapatro

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969380/render-object-and-value-as-json-as-ajax-response/29969770#29969770

Comment: No. based on the error you see it treats `render` as a Collection instead of a method because it treats [] as a getAt operation. And subsequrntly complains that named arguments cannot be used. Similar to any error like `list[a:0]` as compared to list `list[0]`. In order the avoid that confusion since getAt has higher precedance over `as`, braces has to be used. @rahulserver