# How to render arbitrary JSON with the correct content type in Grails?

Tags: json, grails

I'm trying to output something simple like `{"error": "endpoint not available"}`

The snippet below renders with content type *text/html*:

```
render ([error: 'endpoint not available']) as JSON
```

And I've also tried:

```
render(contentType: 'application/json') {
  error {
    "endpoint not available"
  }
}
```

Which I know it doesn't produce the desired JSON.

How can I produce the JSON I want with the *application/json* content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def responseData = [
    'error': 'endpoint not available'
]
render responseData as JSON
```

Comment: That worked, with a content type of _application/json_. Now why the heck did that work and `render ([error: 'endpoint not available']) as JSON` did not?

Comment: @sagas [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16755200/2051952) might be helpful to get what you are looking for. In brief, you have to use the braces appropriately `render ([error: 'endpoint not available'] as JSON)` should work.

Comment: @dmahapatro very helpful and great addition to this answer.